# explorer: remove leftover whitespace after scaling down with transform:scale

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, scale

This is hard to explain ... If you use css scale (and zoom) to zoom down (less than 1), in explorer 9 and 10, the surrounding elements still treat their content area as if it had its original size. for example

```
   transform:scale(0.5);
   width:200%;
```

will be treated as 200% wide, even though its displayed 100% wide.
Let me demonstrate this in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pike/CAbcH/

I see both horizontal and vertical scrollbars in IE10. Using 'zoom' instead has the same effect.

How can I explain explorer it doesnt need scrollbars beyond the content ? A jquery solution is acceptable, too.

Comment: In safari it's 100% wide as it should, but there is, when I scroll, a white 100% area below.

Comment: it's due to `overflow: auto` remove this and it wold fix it. What Is the particular reason you need to add `overflow: auto`

Comment: in the real life situation, i need scrollbars if the content is more than, well, `100%/scale`. yes, i need `overflow:auto`; i need scrollbars, but i want them to be correct.

Comment: i've updated the fiddle to make it behave as intended in firefox, chrome and safari. the only one wrong is now internet explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution - http://jsfiddle.net/pike/YmfGC/

Not all that neat, using browser sniffing, it basicly writes a wrapping `<div>` around the zoomed div, for IE only, using the width() and height() the browser found after rendering the page ...

Comment: accepting my own answer. i wonder how much points thatll give me :-)

Comment: ofcourse, the browser sniffing wont work in IE11 anymore. that browser is called 'trident'.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the overflow:hidden on #scroll and overflow:auto: on #zoomed (ie reversing their overflow basically), making the scrolls function as they should be - is this what you were looking for? Though I have a question on why you would need the to have the scales as you can make it look just as you wanted with css.

Comment: You mean, like in this fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/pike/3c4KJ/ ?  No, you cant do that, because (in most browsers) the scrollbars itself get scaled as well - look at that fiddle in chrome, for example, and see the very strange thin scrollbar. In firefox, its even worse. The scrolling container needs to wrap the zooming container...

Comment: `why you would need the to have the scales` - thats just a fiddle. In the real application, the scale is dynamically set by jquery. I want the container size to stay the same, but the content to zoom in and out. As the fiddle shows, zooming out is a problem.

Comment: I could only get it to work proper on firefox and chrome but not IE :( On IE it didnt scale down the 200% width and height. Perhaps, JQuery is the way to go (?)